# Entity Framework getting data from the ENTIRE column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, system.linq.dynamic

I've got an api call getUser which returns ALL the info from the database at the specified column, but I want to exclude some things; phonenumber, email etc.

Tried fiddling with the LINQ, changeing the modelBuilder, changeing the optionBuilder

Have looked for any SQL saying "Select * from" but found nothing

Deleting things in my UserModel do work, however this is an ugly way of doing it.

```
Result<UserModel> result = new Result<UserModel>();
try
    {
        using (var db = new ComeatDBContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
        {
            var user = db.User
                .Include(f => f.Nationality)
                .Include(f => f.State)
                .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id && !e.IsDeleted);

            result.ResponseObject = (new UserModel()).FromUser(user);
            var house = db.House.FirstOrDefault(e => e.UserId == user.Id);
            if (house != null)
            {
                result.ResponseObject.House = ( new HouseModel() ).FromHouse(house);
            }
            result.Success = true;
        }
```

Expected specifying which data to include (or not include) but instead I get everything unless I set the values to "null" after they've been delievered by the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.FirstOrDefault(...)` is what causes the underlying database query (SQL) to be executed. It will populate all properties that are defined on the entity. The data entity is then transformed to your `UserModel` object when you execute `(new UserModel()).FromUser(user);`.

If you want to reuse your UserModel class but not populate all the columns you can do something like this;

```
var userModel = db.User
     .Select(x => new UserModel { Name = x.Name, Id = x.Id })
     .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id && !e.IsDeleted);

result.ResponseObject = userModel;
```

Comment: Or if you want to limit the response items to a max of one without executing the data, you may use `.Take(1)`

Comment: Unfortunatly that doesn't work " cannot convert from 'PLACEHOLDER.Business.Models.UserModel' to 'PLACEHOLDER.Data.Models.User'

Comment: @MikkelRohdeGlerup - I think you get the error on the row where you assign the result.ResponseObject. Added this line to my response to clarify that you do not need to do (new UserModel()).FromUser(user); anymore...

Comment: @DaggeJ thank you so much! I've been battling this for 2 days now!